# How to replicate the tokenization betweeen CLI input and main(args:Array[String])

Tags: java, arguments, command-line-interface, tokenize

I'm receiving my CLI args as a single string from a config file, they are not coming into

```
def main(args: Array[String])
```

I'm then using Picocli to parse the args, but I need to tokenize the string into an array first, and I don't want to add a full additional lib **picocli-shell-jline3** just for a tokenization function. Is there some tokenizer in the Java standard lib I can use to 100% mimic the tokenization I would get from passing args via the CLI into **main**?

How does the **java** command tokenize the CLI args into an array (and remove extra space, respect quotes, space, etc)?  Or is that actually the OS layer doing it and passing each token into the java program?

I've had no luck googling - keep finding explanations of how to CLI args, not how they are tokenized under in between the CLI and the JVM **main(args:Array[String])** method.

Comment: tokenize ??? it seems to me that you are using the term out of place. which makes your question meaningless

Comment: Java doesn't perform that tokenization at all. That is handled by the shell *before* the application is run.

Comment: I disagree with the tokenize comment:  @mrmcwolf "tokenize" is the correct technical term for what the OP is trying to achieve. The OP is creating an application that receives its command and parameters as a single string (maybe via a network socket, who knows), not as a standard command line application where the shell pre-tokenizes the input. So, the OP needs to tokenize the input String themselves... This is a valid question.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel when invoked as a command line application, the shell takes care of the tokenization of the command line, but when receiving input from, for example, a remote client, the command and its arguments may be sent as a single string via a network socket. This is a valid question.

Comment: @RemkoPopma The OP is asking _"How does the java command tokenize the CLI args into an array"_. And the answer is, it doesn't.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel technically, yes. However, the OP also stated "_I'm receiving my CLI args as a single string (...) I'm then using Picocli to parse the args, but I need to tokenize the string into an array first (...)_". 
I agree they then phrased their question a bit messily ;-) but it was still clear to me what they were actually asking.

Comment: and it is not clear to me yet ... "tokenization" is when we have the replacement of sensitive information, which is transmitted publicly with an insignificant key (token) by which the information can be extracted (if necessary). however, the context of the question is "how to validate user input in java".

Comment: @mrmcwolf that is what tokenization means in the context of data security, yes. However, this is a question about parsing (language processing), so we are clearly talking about the other meaning of tokenization: _"(...) tokenization is the process of converting a sequence of characters (...) into a sequence of lexical tokens (strings (...))."_ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis
(I don't see any mention of "how to validate user input in java" in the question. It is purely about splitting a single string into tokens/words.)

Answer (score 0):

The logic that is used internally by picocli to parse [@-files](https://picocli.info/#AtFiles) (a relatively similar scenario) looks like the below. It is not perfect, but hopefully good enough to meet your requirements:

```java
String line = // get single String with options and parameters (and maybe subcommands)

StreamTokenizer tok = new StreamTokenizer(new StringReader(line));
tok.resetSyntax();
tok.wordChars(' ', 255);
tok.whitespaceChars(0, ' ');
tok.quoteChar('"');
tok.quoteChar('\'');
tok.commentChar('#');

List<String> arguments = new ArrayList<>();
while (tok.nextToken() != StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF) {
    arguments.add(tok.sval);
}

// now do something with the arguments list...
```